# Prolog is printing the value but does not print true if the condition is satisfied

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

[SS for true condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma306.png)
[SS for false condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlcOr.png)
Why is it that it prints false but not true and how can I fix it

Expected it to print both true and false.....not just false.

P.S. I have just started prolog so I am an absolute Newb

Comment: If you're completely new to it, why are you expecting anything? There's no need to print true, you can see it's true by getting an answer. Easiest to change your expectations to fit how it works,